# I have a problem evaluating an ODE in Mathematica, where the error asks me to define a dependent variable?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a series of linked ODEs in Mathematica (where the system describes the trajectory of a ball through the air).

```
eqns = {q''[t] ==-VH(r (q'[t])+L(s'[t])), 
s''[t] ==-VH(r (s'[t])-L(q'[t])),
w''[t] ==-VHr(w'[t])-g}

eps = 10^-5;

sol = NDSolve[{q''[t] ==-VH(r (q'[t])+L(s'[t])), 
s''[t] ==-VH(r (s'[t])-L(q'[t])),
w''[t] ==-VHr(w'[t])-g, q[eps] == s[eps] == w[eps] == eps},{q'[t], s'[t], w'[t]},{q, s, w}, {t,0, 1}]
```

I have tried with the above code but the error I get is the following:

```
The dependent variable q'[t] is not clearly specified in the form f[q,t].
```

I have been wracking my brain and trying different things for hours. Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: 1. This `{q, s, w}` list is not needed and it confuses Mathematica. After removing it, however, there is a problem that you 2. did not specify parameters. NDSolve is a purely numerical routine and you need to give the numeric values to app parameters, and 3. The initial conditionsare not enough.

Comment: Or, `sol = DSolve[{q''[t] == -VH (r (q'[t]) + L (s'[t])),  s''[t] == -VH (r (s'[t]) - L (q'[t])), w''[t] == -VHr (w'[t]) - g}, {q[t], s[t], w[t]}, t] // Flatten` gives a symbolic solution, to which you can apply boundary conditions later, if you wish.

Comment: Cross posted to the top of https://www.reddit.com/r/Mathematica